# how to set baseUrl in nuxt/axios?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, axios, nuxt.js

baseURL doen't set in nuxt axios mudule and i cant authenticat with nxut/auth module.

this is nuxt.config.js:

```
 auth: {
        strategies: {
            local: {
                endpoints: {
                    login: {url: 'auth/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'data.access_token'},
                    user: {url: 'user', method: 'get', propertyName: 'data'},
                    logout: {url: 'auth/logout', method: 'post'}
                },
                tokenRequired: true,
                tokenType: 'Bearer',
            },
            redirect: {
                home: '/',
                login: '/login',
                logout: '/logout'
            }
        }
    },


 axios: {
        baseURL: "api.dvl/api/v1/"
    },
```

everything is right, but if i make a request, it request to http://localhost:3000/auth/login

what is wrong?

my login page:

```
 data() {
            return {
                title: process.env.title.fa,
                form: {
                    email: null,
                    password: null,
                    remember: false
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            async login() {
                await this.$axios.$post('/login', this.form)
                this.$auth.login({ data: this.form })
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your async login is wrong. Try the code below:

```
 methods: {
    async login() {
      await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
        data: {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        }
      })
      this.checkLogin()
    },

    checkLogin() {
      console.log(this.$auth.user)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please share some explanation such that others can learn from your answer - what exactly was wrong, and how does your code work different?

Comment: You have used nuxt-auth module and set it local strategy in nuxt config. So, for login, you have to use $auth.loginwith('local', data).

Answer (score 0):

that because in client side requests axios cant use environmental variables then
you should use runtime config for axios in nuxt config
try this :

```
export default {
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],

  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:4000', // Used as fallback if no runtime config is provided
  },

  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      browserBaseURL: process.env.BASE_URL
    }
  },

  privateRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL
    }
  },
}
```